# Why Debugging is not easy or built in VSCode for C++ as that for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Every time ,I click Run and Debug ,cpp file ,I get to this file,"launch.json"
.There is not much enough help in this regard on youtube,also ,I could not solve this problem from VSCode official documentation.

my cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int iam;
    std::cout<<"salam from Pakistan!";
    cout<<endl<<"enter number";
    cin>>iam;
    return 0;
}
```

launch.json file

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": ["-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Also ,I dont know what is this tasks.json file which I see along with launch.json in .vscode folder.

Comment: your `launch.json` looks like a `tasks.json` file, VS code can generate a basic `launch.json` for you by selecting one of the options from the debug menu

Comment: VSC is NOT an IDE, it is an editor with benefits. Because it runs on JavaScript likely it supports it best, Use Visual Studio if you want an easy C++ development environment, Qt Creator

Answer (score 1):

Delete your current `launch.json`, then open your file and go to `Run` -> `StartDebugging`. This should guide you through choosing compiler and debugger and should generate your launch.json file which should look like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, you have a `task` defined and not a `configuration`.

The tasks.json looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```